# How to display multiple lines of text in SVG?

Tags: html, svg

Is it possible to display multiple lines of text in SVG without using the `dy` property? I'm using SVG 1.1 but might be able to use 1.2.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text x="0" y="15" font-size="15">
    <tspan>tspan line 1</tspan>
    <tspan>tspan line 2</tspan>
    <tspan>tspan line 3</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I've typed the code above. I want the text all flush to the left and each `tspan` to be a new line. Is `tspan` the only tag I can use? I want SVG to position the text lines vertically with line breaks. I do not want to manually enter the `dy`.

According to what I've read, each line should appear below the other. They are but they are also staggered across.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <text x="0" y="0" font-size="15">
    <tspan dy="15">tspan line 1</tspan>
    <tspan dy="15">tspan line 2</tspan>
    <tspan dy="15">tspan line 3</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

I guess it is required to add the `x` property. If you are setting the `dy` property to a fixed value, what happens when you change the font size?

This is working better than what I started with:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xml:space="preserve">
  <text x="0" y="0" font-size="15" font-family="courier new" dy="0">
    <tspan x="0" dy="15">tspan line 1</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="15">tspan line 2</tspan>
    <tspan x="0" dy="15">tspan line 3</tspan>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Is there a way to apply the `x` and `dy` to all the `tspan`s? Maybe a property like `line-height` on the `text` element?

It doesn't look like the text tag has a property to set the delta y. It has been suggested in the comments to use JQuery to set the `x` attribute of all `tspan`s. It looks like the `dy` property can accept other types of values such as points and percentages!? Is there a way to set the `dy` to a value that is 120% of the font size of its parent text element? I've tried to set it to 120%, but it doesn't seem to work like I expect. When I set 120% in the `dy` property, it goes off the screen. When I set it to `12` or `12px` it stays in the same position. If I set it to `12%`, it shifts slightly but is not 120% or 12px.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqBRmd

It looks like it can accept any of the following:
http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLength

I've also looked up acceptable value types for `dy` and `dx`, and I can't make sense of it [http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TSpanElementDXAttribute.](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TSpanElementDXAttribute)

**UPDATE 4:**
Thanks for the answers so far. It looks like there is a way to display multiple lines of text spaced apart relatively. See my answer below.

Comment: `jQuery('tspan').attr('x','0')` sets ALL the `tspan` to `0`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It looks like this will space the lines one after another without hard-coding a font size in each `tspan`. Font at 15px:

```html
<svg style="border:1px solid black" >
    <text x="0" y="0" font-size="15" dy="0">
        <tspan x="0" dy=".6em">tspan line 1</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 2</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

If you change the font size the lines continue to be spaced at `120%` apart from each other or `1.2em`. Font at 20px:

```html
<svg style="border:1px solid black" >
    <text x="0" y="0" font-size="20" dy="0">
        <tspan x="0" dy=".6em">tspan line 1</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 2</tspan>
        <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Example - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXMVqo

Comment: Technically the `x="0"` in the `<text>` element is unnecessary, since you are setting `x` in all of the sub `<tspan>` elements. One of the things I hate about how SVG does text is that you have to hard code the x position, and duplicate it for all the sub elements.

Answer (score 5):

just calculate the heights:

```js
var drawx=part.x||0;
var drawy=part.y||0;
var fontSize=part.fontSize||14; 
var lineHeight=part.lineHeight||1.25; 
var style=part.style||""; 
var fontFamily=part.fontFamily||"Arial"; 
var text=part.text.split('\n').map(function(a,i){ return '<tspan x="'+drawx+'" y="'+(drawy+fontSize*lineHeight+i*fontSize*lineHeight)+'">'+a+'</tspan>' }).join('\n');

tqrSvg+='<text x="'+drawx+'" y="'+drawy+'" style="'+style+'" font-family="'+fontFamily+'" font-size="'+fontSize+'">'+text+'</text>'
```

Answer (score 3):

tspan is the right way to do it. And this is how:

```
<tspan x="10" dy="15">tspan line 1</tspan>
```

reference: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/tspan-element.html

Comment: Not sure why this is modded up. The very first sentence of the question: `without using the dy property`

Comment: @Dan it doesn't "demand" to be done w/o `dy` but rather "asks" if it can be done in some automatic way. Later in the question it states `I do not want to manually enter the dy`. The keyword "manually" (to me) implies anything goes, even `dy` as long as it's convenient. That said this answer doesn't really provide a good example/solution.