# chordNetwork - wrap text in labels

Tags: r, networkd3

I have a problem with wrapping of a long text (separated by a semicolon) in `chordNetwork` (in the [networkd3](/questions/tagged/networkd3) package) labels.

I tried paste `"\n"` after semicolon but didn't work.

Result which I want in label:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; 
yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy
```

Here is the code:

```
# create a simple data frame
d2 <- data.frame(from=LETTERS[1:5],to=c("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;\n yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy","X","X","Y","Y"),v=runif(5),stringsAsFactors = F)
d2
# convert data frame into  a square matrix for chordNetwork data structure
d2 <- rbind(d2, data.frame(from=d2$to,to=d2$from,v=NA))
d2
str(d2)

library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(networkD3)

d2 %>%  spread(key = to,value = v) %>% select(-from) %>% as.matrix() ->d2
rownames(d2) <- colnames(d2)
d2;dim(d2)

chordNetwork(d2, height = 500, width = 500, initialOpacity = 0.8,
             useTicks = 0,  padding = 0.1, fontSize = 9,
             fontFamily = "sans-serif", labels = colnames(d2), labelDistance = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG text elements do not support linebreaks. see, for instance...

[How to linebreak an svg text within javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701522/how-to-linebreak-an-svg-text-within-javascript)

[How to display multiple lines of text in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469134/how-to-display-multiple-lines-of-text-in-svg)