# Centered text both vertical and horizontal inside a circle

Tags: svg

I wanted to center text (two rows) vertically and horizontally inside this circle, but something went wrong:

[SVG wrong](https://configurator.kriger.nl/layout/frontend/products/svg/business-02-text.svg)

[SVG wrong preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7WVF.png)

I also tried to place a background image in the center, but i would like it to come under the dotted/dashed border layer, not above it. Any suggestion please?

Here is how the text should be, but I want it as text, not as tspan. And of course a centered background image under it.

[Good example](https://configurator.kriger.nl/layout/frontend/products/svg/business-02.svg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use `tspan`, you'll need two `text` elements. You can set both elements' coordinates to 50%/50%, and then..

- To center horizontally on that point, use [text-anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/text-anchor) `middle`.
- To place the first row just above that point, and the second row just below it, use [alignment-baseline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/alignment-baseline) `baseline/hanging` (to get more space between the rows, you'll need to adjust the `y` coordinates a bit).

Example:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
    <style>
        text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    </style>

    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="20" fill="none" />
    
    <!-- Anchors in action -->
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="baseline">First row</text>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" alignment-baseline="hanging">Second row</text>
</svg>
```

**Edit**

With more than two lines, it's easier to use one `text` element with multiple `tspan` elements. Again, center the `text` at 50%/50%, and space the `tspan`s evenly using the [`dy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/dy) attribyte. *Notice how `dy` is relative to the previous `tspan`*:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">
    <style>
        text {
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 30px;
        }
        tspan {
            alignment-baseline: central;
        }
    </style>

    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="45%" stroke="tomato" stroke-width="8" stroke-dasharray="20" fill="none" />

    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle">
        <tspan x="50%" dy="-2em">First row</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" dy="1em">Second row</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" dy="1em">Third row</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" dy="1em">Fourth row</tspan>
        <tspan x="50%" dy="1em">Fifth row</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, those alignments made it. It works good. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Still one more question: what if I have 5 lines and want to have them all vertically centered one below the other?

Comment: @DanielIlaş I've updated my answer with a multi-line solution. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469134/how-to-display-multiple-lines-of-text-in-svg