# Chartist pie chart with label need on next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, chartist.js

I have pie chart with custom label and percentage. 
Issue is Label and percentage appears in same line. 
I need to break percentage and label into two lines. 
Label 
percentage

I have try `<br>` and `\n` but did not work. Please help

```js
var names = ['', 'Home Loans', 'Auto Loans'];

var data = {
  series: [3, 5, 4]
};

var sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b
};

new Chartist.Pie('.ct-chart', data, {
  labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, idx) {
    var percentage = Math.round(value / data.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
    return names[idx] + '\n' + percentage;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.11.0/chartist.min.js"></script>
<div class="ct-chart"></div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but for now, using this library, it's impossible.

The only option to break a line in svg is to split it to `tspan`s. 
(See [How to display multiple lines of text in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31509120/863110)).

To do this, chartist have to change their code of `labelInterpolationFnc` call: instead of using [`text`](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/blob/develop/src/scripts/core.js#L989) the need to allow `html` so you could split the text by yourself.

Something like:

```js
labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, idx) {
  var percentage = Math.round(value / data.series.reduce(sum) * 100) + '%';
  return `
    <tspan>${names[idx]}</tspan>
    <tspan>${percentage}</tspan>
  `;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't be clear enough. For now, it's impossible: `To do this, chartist have to change their code of labelInterpolationFnc call`

Answer (score 0):

Mosh Feu's answer didn't work me, 'cause Chartist rendered `< tspan>...</ tspan >` content like a simple string and not like an HTML-code.

[This issue](https://github.com/gionkunz/chartist-js/issues/25#issuecomment-58036179) gave me an idea, which consist in `draw` event handler:

```
.on('draw', function(data) {

    if (data.type === 'label') {
        let textHtml = ['<p>', data.text, '</p>'].join('');

        let multilineText = Chartist.Svg('svg').foreignObject(
            textHtml,
            {
                style: 'overflow: visible;',
                x: data.x - 30,
                y: data.y - 50,
                width: 130,
                height: 20
            },
            'ct-label'
        );
        data.element.replace(multilineText);
    }
```

[Codepen for your case is here.](https://codepen.io/Boolean_Type/pen/oNxOwrx)