# SVG text and white-space:pre compatibility

Tags: css, svg, line-breaks

This SVG text will be displayed in 2 lines on Firefox, but in just 1 line on Chrome:

```js
document.querySelector("text").textContent = "This is the first line \n This is the second line";
```

```css
text {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="10" y="50"></text>
</svg>
```

Is there any reliable source describing the current compatibility of `white-space: pre;` in an SVG text with newline characters? I've looked at MDN, Caniuse etc. but couldn't find anything.

(by the way I believe there's nothing in the specs and Firefox implementation decided to do that independently, is that correct?)

Comment: Sorry, there are no multyline layout concepts available for svg `<text>`  elements. You need to emulate line breaks by splitting text into `<tspan>` elements. See [How to display multiple lines of text in SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469134/how-to-display-multiple-lines-of-text-in-svg). There is a draft of a [`inline-size`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#InlineSize) attribute but it's currently not supported by any major browser.

Comment: @herrstrietzel thanks for your comment, but I know all that (tspan) already. I'm just asking about this strange Firefox implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- white-space was not an SVG property in SVG 1.1
- white-space is an SVG property in [SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/text.html#TextWhiteSpace) and should work as it does with HTML text
- [only Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) has implemented this part of the SVG 2 specification so far

Comment: Thanks a lot, and specially thanks for the "Browser compatibility" link.