# Python SVG multi line text

Tags: python, svg, pycairo

I am currently trying to generate svgs with multi-line text inside of them with Python.

For that I tried the [pycairo](https://pycairo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library:

```html
    cr.move_to(20, 30)
    cr.show_text("Most relationships seem so transitory")
```

The issue I have with that approach is that it is unable to create line-breaks so the text overflow at the right side if it is longer.
Is there an approach to create svgs with multiline-text without the text overflowing?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no line break in svg. Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31469134/how-to-display-multiple-lines-of-text-in-svg As an altrenative you can use a foreignObject for the text.